# How can I make cpp to distinguish input(cin)?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve the question in programming : principles and practice using c++

Q. make a code that reads two int values and prints them. Make '|' input stop the program.
use while loop

I have no idea to distinguish whether the input is int or '|'

Comment: [DUPLICATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63812030/exit-while-loop-when-character-is-entered/63812347?noredirect=1#comment112840853_63812347)

Answer (score 2):

This question:

> make a code that reads two int values and prints them. Make '|' input stop the program. use while loop

indicates that author doesn't know c++ well or task was stated for different language. It is also possible you didn't copy paste whole description of task.

When next character to read is `|` trying reading integer value will fail, so no special check has to be done.

So just read pairs of `int` values until error occurs. Special check for `|` is obsolete.

```cpp
    int a, b;
    while (std::cin >> a >> b)
        std::cout << (a + b) << '\n';
```

https://godbolt.org/z/P95z4a

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    
    string value1, value2;
   
    while(1) //infinity loop
    {
    
    cout << "Enter value one" << endl;
        cin >> value1;
        cout << "Enter value two" << endl;
        cin >> value2;
    
    if(value1 == "|" || value2 == "|") // the || is a logical OR. If v1 oder v2 is | break the while loop
        {
            break;
        }
    
    cout << value1 << " + " << value2 << " = " << (std::stoi(value1)+std::stoi(value2)) << endl; //std::stoi makes a string a number, so it means string to int

    }

    return 0;
    
}
```

Compile it with the c++11 flag for stdoi:

```
g++ -std=c++11 example.cpp -o example
```

PS: don't ask stackoverflow to do your homework for you. Try to learn for yourself. You will need it in the job and your colleagues will depend on you.

Comment: thank you for your advice.  im trying to learn cpp as a hobby but it is hard to me yet. :(

Comment: it is a bit old, bit a recommend "C++ von A bis Z" von Jürgen Wolf if you speak German. There are good english books out there too. Try to read one, it is how I learned to write C++ when I was 15.

Answer (score 0):

You can pour your input into string type variable `cin >> tmp_str`. Then check if it is euqal to `'|'`, if not you can convert it to integer using `stoi` or any alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the user input as a string and checking whether it's equal to `|`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    
    while (input != "|") {
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        // read int values here
    }
}
```